# DELETE all duplicate topics with few conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates, sql-delete

I'm trying to make sql who will delete all duplicate titles BUT must delete duplicates with these conditions:

- must delete only duplicates with same **object_id**
- must keep only the newest record (biggest **topic_id**)  (topic_id is the unique id for every topic AI)

So far I've done that (testing with select...)

```
SELECT topic_id,object_id,title,url,date 
FROM topics GROUP BY title 
HAVING ( COUNT(title) > 1) 
ORDER BY topic_id DESC
```

But doesn't meet the conditions.
I'm using mysql.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `MySQL`, you cannot specify the target table to a `DML` operation in a subquery (unless you nest it more than one level deep, but in this case you won't get reliable results and cannot use correlated subqueries).

Use a `JOIN`:

```
DELETE  td
FROM    topics td
JOIN    topics ti
ON      ti.object_id = td.object_id
        AND ti.title = td.title
        AND ti.topic_id > td.topic_id;
```

Create an index on `topics (object_id, title, topic_id)` for this to work fast.

Comment: Thanks, seems it will do the job.

Answer (score 1):

This will delete all duplicate object_id records save the one with the highest topic_id.

```
delete from topics outer where exists
(
    select 1 from topics inner where 
        outer.object_id = inner.object_id AND 
        inner.topic_id  < outer.topic_id
)
```

Comment: Wont't work in `MySQL`. Will result in `Error Code: 1093 You can't specify target table for update in FROM clause`

Comment: Besides, `inner` and `outer` are keywords

Answer (score 0):

First, if you have a date field, you'd do better identifying the newest records by their date.

This will work :

```
SELECT topic_id, object_id, title, url, date 
FROM   topics earlier
WHERE  EXISTS 
    (SELECT newest.topic_id 
     FROM   topics newest 
     WHERE  newest.date      > earlier.date 
     AND    newest.object_id = earlier.object_id)
```

You're selecting the lines for which exists another line with the same object_id and a more recent date.

Answer (score -1):

WITH tbl AS (SELECT topic_id, object_id, row_number() over(partition by object_id order by topic_id DESC) as rnum
FROM topics)
DELETE tbl WHERE rnum > 1

For more information please check this article:
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/06/23/sql-server-2005-2008-delete-duplicate-rows/